# When is Node.js a bad choice for a ASP.NET MVC developer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js

I've been looking at Node.js and the different articles for deploying an ASP.NET MVC 3 application on it. My question is when does using Node **not** make sense? I've seen some comments along the lines of "not a great solution for heavy web + database CRUD applications or for serving static content." and I'd like to know peoples thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [Bad Use Cases](http://nodeguide.com/convincing_the_boss.html) on [nodeguide](http://nodeguide.com/) which also contains good explanations on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that node.js brings nothing to the table that you don't already have with ASP.NET MVC. You can use asynchronous action methods for example. Almost all .NET IO-related APIs have an asynchronous version available.

With the upcoming async support in C# 5.0 it will also become much easier to do asynchronous code in C# than it is in node.js.

That said, it is a nice property of node.js that you can share server code with the browser. This is, in my opinion, the main advantage.

You need to decide whether that advantage is enough or not.